# Flash AS3 - Access external swf on the same domain

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I ran into this problem and could not solve it, so I have a swf file that loads assets from 
another swf file, everything's fine, until I put them on the server, they are under the same
domain, relative path doesnt work nor does absolute path. This is not even a cross domain
problem, since both files are on the same server.

Did anyone ever have the same problem?
Thanks.

Comment: describe the error you are getting.

also, if you run under firebug, the network tab should show you if it is trying to load the assets.

Comment: what file policy have you set? local or network?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Flex Builder you can set the right -use-network compiler flag.
If you're using Flash IDE and the content is on the same server, make sure 
you've got the *Local playback security* set to 'Access local files only', in the Flash
tab under Publish Settings.

[alt text http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/local_network_playback/fig01.jpg](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/local_network_playback/fig01.jpg)

That should do it. As Dru stated, what is the error message you are receiving ?

The images comes from [this article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/local_network_playback.html) which might come in handy.

Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ultrashock.com/forums/actionscript/loader-problem-with-swf-from-same-domain-123692.html
try this , maybe can help